# Extracting .png images from a .plist file

Tags: plist

I need to update some .png images for the iPad 3 retina display. The only issue is that these .png images are in a .plist file.

So...
1) Can I extract .png files manually from the .plist file? Or is there a program that does that?
or, 2) Can I edit the resolution of the .png files that are on the .plist file... an example...

```
    <key>opponent_left_1.png</key>
    <dict>
        <key>frame</key>
        <string>{{1914,1764},{88,81}}</string>
        <key>offset</key>
        <string>{41,-35}</string>
        <key>sourceSize</key>
        <string>{334,355}</string>
    </dict>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The PNGs aren't inside the PLIST file, it's just a simple text file. They are probably inside a Resources folder, which is associated to this PLIST file (answer based on Mac OS X package architecture).

Answer (score 0):

This is a code for extracting .png images. Create *extract.py* file with this code and run from command line: 
`extract.py name_of_sheet_without_extension`

This script create a folder with extracted .png files.

```
#! /usr/lical/bin/python
import os,Image,sys
from xml.etree import ElementTree

def tree_to_dict(tree):
    d = {}
    for index, item in enumerate(tree):
        if item.tag == 'key':
            if tree[index+1].tag == 'string':
                d[item.text] = tree[index + 1].text
            elif tree[index + 1].tag == 'true':
                d[item.text] = True
            elif tree[index + 1].tag == 'false':
                d[item.text] = False
            elif tree[index+1].tag == 'dict':
                d[item.text] = tree_to_dict(tree[index+1])
    return d

def gen_png_from_plist(plist_filename, png_filename):
    file_path = plist_filename.replace('.plist', '')
    big_image = Image.open(png_filename)
    root = ElementTree.fromstring(open(plist_filename, 'r').read())
    plist_dict = tree_to_dict(root[0])
    to_list = lambda x: x.replace('{','').replace('}','').split(',')
    for k,v in plist_dict['frames'].items():
        print "-----start\n----------"
        rectlist = to_list(v['frame'])
        print rectlist, "--------rectlist"
        offset = to_list(v['offset'])
        print offset, "--------offset"
        width = int( rectlist[3] if v['rotated'] else rectlist[2] )
        height = int( rectlist[2] if v['rotated'] else rectlist[3] )
        print width,height,"----width,height"
        box=( 
            int(rectlist[0]),
            int(rectlist[1]),
            int(rectlist[0]) + width,
            int(rectlist[1]) + height,
            )
        # bos is start & end point
        print box,"-----_box-"
        print v['rotated'], "---rotated"

        sizelist = [ int(x) for x in to_list(v['sourceSize'])]
        rect_on_big = big_image.crop(box)
        if v['rotated']:
            rect_on_big = rect_on_big.rotate(90)
        result_image = Image.new('RGBA', sizelist, (0,0,0,0))
        if v['rotated']:
            result_box=(
                (sizelist[0] - height)/2 + int(offset[0]),
                (sizelist[1] - width)/2 - int(offset[1]),
                (sizelist[0] + height)/2 + int(offset[0]),
                (sizelist[1] + width)/2 - int(offset[1])
            )
        else:
            result_box=(
                (sizelist[0] - width)/2 + int(offset[0]),
                (sizelist[1] - height)/2 - int(offset[1]),
                (sizelist[0] + width)/2 + int(offset[0]),
                (sizelist[1] + height)/2 - int(offset[1])
            )
        result_image.paste(rect_on_big, result_box, mask=0)
        if not os.path.isdir(file_path):
            os.mkdir(file_path)
        outfile = (file_path+'/' + k).replace('gift_', '')
        print result_box,"-----result_box-"
        print outfile, "generated"
        result_image.save(outfile)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    filename = sys.argv[1]
    plist_filename = filename + '.plist'
    png_filename = filename + '.png'
    if (os.path.exists(plist_filename) and os.path.exists(png_filename)):
        gen_png_from_plist( plist_filename, png_filename )
    else:
        print "make sure you have boith plist and png files in the same directory"
```

Comment: Nice) have a "pack back" script?)

Comment: and Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "extract.py", line 79, in <module>
    gen_png_from_plist( plist_filename, png_filename )
  File "extract.py", line 22, in gen_png_from_plist
    root = ElementTree.fromstring(open(plist_filename, 'r').read())
  File "c:\Python25\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 963, in XML
    parser.feed(text)
  File "c:\Python25\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1245, in feed
    self._parser.Parse(data, 0)
xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 2, column 101

Answer (score 0):

.plist contain information of different png file which is zipped in one mazior png. If you have .plist and his associated .png file then you can unzipped using TextureUnpacker.

If you have Java in your PC or you may be install then you can use TextureUnpacker to unpack .plist file. It also has support .pack file that use in LibGdx projects and .xml file used in many engine like unity to pack texture.

https://github.com/itsabhiaryan/TextureUnPacker